# LinkedIn javascript API: Pass dynamic parameter

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I want to pass API key dynamically to LinkedIn Library call,

I am getting that API key from a database field and saving it in global javascript variable 'myJavascriptVariable' but when I pass it to API on load . It is not accepting it and throwing exception.

What to do?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=false">
        api_key:   myJavascriptVariable
        credentials_cookie: true
        authorize: true
</script>
```

**EDIT:** Error "You must specify a valid JavaScript API Domain as part of this key's configuration."

Comment: Is the error saying that myJavascriptVariable is undefined?

Comment: can you load this piece of code dynamically, and add the API key from backend at the time of load in the correct position?

Comment: @Shivi updated post with error statement.

Comment: @liberalTGM would you please demonstrate what you are suggesting as I didn't get it.

Comment: It would depend on exactly where you are setting your dynamic variable. I am assuming that you get the variable after page load, otherwise you could have set it from backend, in which case, you can either get this snippet from backend or use @itamar piece of code.

Answer (score 1):

The content of that script element is **not** JavaScript. It is a configuration file used by LinkedIn's JavaScript. It cannot contain variables.

You might be able to use a JavaScript variable if you edit the configuration data (e.g. with `innerHTML`, but your timing would have to catch it before LinkedIn's JS tried to read it (which would almost certainly be before the `load` event fired).

You would be better off generating this *server side*.

Comment: I have customized the call so certainly all the API calls are being sent after the library is loaded.Please can you demonstrate what you are saying? how can I pass the value dynamically?

Comment: @HappyDev — It isn't about when the API calls are sent, it is about when the library reads the content of the script element. I would be astonished if that wasn't "immediately as the script loads (by identifying the (current) last script in the document)". Use a server side approach.

Answer (score 0):

I would dynamically create the script tag after you get the variable.

```
var LIScript = document.createElement('script');
LIScript.type = 'text/javascript';
LIScript.src = '//platform.linkedin.com/in.js?async=false';
LIScript.text = "api_key:  "+myJavascriptVariable+"
        credentials_cookie: true
        authorize: true";

document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(LIScript);
```

Although I am not sure this will solve your problem - you can use the `defer` and `async` attributes to control when during the load process the script is executed.